# Laravel nova How to create custom field with multiple input fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I need to create a custom field, that has multiple rows, one row for each day of the week, and multiple input fields, container opening hours and some other stuff, any body who can help me in the right direction?

I have tried to read the documentation, but there is no documentation for advanced custom fields.

Comment: https://github.com/sadekd/nova-opening-hours-field